# Simple php/pdo; Blanks when using sql alias (TableAlias.AmbiguousColumnName)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this simple php/pdo code:

```
<?php
    include 'dbcon.php';

    $stmt = $db->prepare('select * from tbl_request r inner join tbl_category c on r.id_category = c.id where r.id_user = :id_user');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id_user' => $_SESSION['id_user']));
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
?>
<table class="datagrid1">
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['r.dts_create']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['c.name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['r.title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['r.description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['r.flag']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

And it's returning blanks. It doesn't have any problems when I don't use joins and aliases. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it the correct way $row['r.dts_create']; should't it be $row['dts_create'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

It always helps to see the data structure.

```
print_r($data);
```

you get an array of arrays where each array contains value with both index and column name as key like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [username] => admin
            [1] => admin
```

So you have to access with using table column as key of the array. In your case

```
        <td><?php echo $row['dts_create']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['flag']; ?></td>
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to fix it in the SELECT query level first? Meaning that I should't just use SELECT * but specify the specific column names/aliases

Comment: alias has no effect on how you get the data. You need to fix it on how you access it. You have to access it through column name. like `$row['dts_create']`, not `$row['r.dts_create']`

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks! So basically I shouldn't be lazy and name the columns in my select instead of just using *